# Place a component inside label of form control label in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was working with material ui v5 and while using FormControlLabel, I wanted to display my customized component with some text and a button but I'm not able to add space between text and button.

I tried using `justifyContent="space-between"` for Box component from `"@mui/material/Box"` but still no change

[image]

This is what I get but i want space between "item" and delete button.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
// import FormGroup from "@mui/material/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";

const useStyle = makeStyles({
  label: {
    // backgroundColor: "red",
    width: "100%",
    // position: "absolute",
    // right: "10px",
  },
});

export default function TaskItem() {
  const classes = useStyle();
  const Label = (
    <Box
      display="flex"
      justifyContent="space-between"
      alignItems="center"
      className={classes.label}
    >
      <Typography>Item</Typography>
      <IconButton aria-label="delete" size="large">
        <DeleteIcon fontSize="inherit" />
      </IconButton>
    </Box>
  );
  return (
    <>
      <FormControlLabel
        label={Label}
        control={<Checkbox />}
        sx={{ width: "100%" }}
      />
      {/* <Label /> */}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[API of Box component](https://mui.com/components/box/#api) doesn't include properties you try to pass. However, it includes [SX prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/) and you can achieve the effect you want by configuring `sx` property:

```
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        gap: 2
      }}
    >
    ...
```

Comment: I'm confused because they never added alignItems and justifyContent prop in API docs of the box but when I use, they work exactly the same as they would if we pass sx prop. Also, I want this custom label to occupy the width of the parent, any solution?